# Initial values in Formik aren't showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, forms, formik, yup

I have created a separate component in which it will render a card with form inside it. I used Formik API to handle it. This is my code.

---

```
function ParentComponent(){
    return (
        <View>
            <ChildComponent someDataFromApi={details}/>
        </View
    )
}
```

---

```
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

function ChildComponent(){
const someSchema={
    firstName: Yup.string().required().label("First Name"),
    lastName: Yup.string().required().label("Last Name"),
}
return (
   <Formik
       initialValues={first_name: details.first_name, last_name: details.last_name, }
       validationSchema={someSchema}
       onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
   >
       <Field label={"First Name"} name="firstName">
       <Field label={"Last Name"} name="lastName">
   </Formik>
}
```

---

I don't know why it doesn't show the initialValues for the fields, I tried console logging it and it returns correct values means it already catches the data from initialValues, it just doesn't show it in the field.

Comment: I think you need to give the same name to your initial values as you did in naming you field.

<Field name="something" => initialValues={{ something: value }}

It might be how formik knows to glue stuff together. ( I didn't check the documentation, will do later)

Comment: Also tried doing that, no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `initialValues` are passed via the props as provided in [the documentation](https://formik.org/docs/guides/react-native). Here is a minimal working example.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

import { Formik, Field } from "formik";

function ParentComponent() {
    return (
        <View>
            <ChildComponent someDataFromApi={{details: {
              first_name: "Hello",
              last_name: "World"
            }}}/>
        </View>
    )
}

function ChildComponent(props) {
    const details = props.someDataFromApi

   return <View>
        <Formik
            initialValues={details}
            onSubmit={() => {}}
        >
          {(props) => {
              return <View>
                <Field
                    value={props.values.details.first_name}
                />
              </View>
          }}
        </Formik>
      </View>
}


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{margin: 20}}>
      <ParentComponent></ParentComponent>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Done! It seems like I can't upvote your answer yet because my reputation score is still lower than the minimum required reputation to do so. I think I'll just get back on this thread once I have enough reputation score. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I think field names and initialValues parameter in your code should be the same.

[image]